# How to pause a php script launched with crontab?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a PHP scraper running every night on a very large site. Crontab launches the script at 2am and pkill it at 7am. Now I am concerned that brutally killing the script might result in data loss. Let's say that crontab calls the script off while the script is busy writing my scraped data into the database, then the next day the database will refuse that last/first record because it is already present (even if not completely).

Is there any way I can freeze the script with crontab? (That is, without adding a sleep() to my script)

Comment: Instead of killing it, you could `kill -STOP pid`, and later `kill -CONT pid`.

Comment: That could potentially cause problems if you have an open database connection, or are holding a lock on something someone else wants to use in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say that crontab calls the script off while the script is busy writing my scraped data into the database

That would be a problem, since you will run into some transaction timeout or something, if you stop your process externally. A better way would be to let the script halt/pause on its own. You could for example define some marker file that is checked by the script periodically so that the script can halt/pause in a controlled way.

Answer (score 0):

Having one large cronjob that can't be interrupted is usually a sign of bad design for a number of reasons.

Most notably, **you can't interrupt the run** for no reason whatsoever or you'll end up with corrupted data. This can become a big problem in case you have an unexpected *power loss* or  *server crash*.

Also, **it doesn't scale**. If you need to process more data, you can't scale it to multiple servers. If you have run times of a few hours now, you may end up exhausting a complete server very soon.

I would recommend to seriously rethink the functionality of this cronjob and *restructure* it so you have a number of *smaller tasks* that are queued up somewhere. (It can even be the database.) You could then **mask the `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signals** when processing a single task and *check the received signals in between tasks*. This will allow you to notify the process using either of the aforementioned and have it shut down gracefully.

That being said, things do break and servers do crash. I also urge you to **work out plans for data recovery** in case the cronjob breaks down while working on something.